# sencha touch 2 numberfield separator

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I have an ST2 app that has a numberfield for the phone number:

```
            {
                    xtype: 'numberfield',
                    id: 'Phone',
                    name: 'Phone',
                    cls: "detailText",
                    label: 'Phone:'
            }
```

I have this running on both Android and iPhone.
If I enter a phone number of "555123987", the Android will display "555123987" while the iPhone will display "555,123,987".

How do I remove the commas?

I'm using a numberfield because elsewhere in the app the user uses the contents of the field to make a call. Is there another way to stop junk characters getting in there without watching keydown or something? Maybe using textfield with a regex somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the ui config to `text` (**`ui: 'text'`**). Like so:

```
xtype: 'numberfield',
ui: 'text',
label: 'Phone',
name: 'phone'
```

That's a quick way to prevent the commas from automatically getting in there on iPhone. But it doesn't prevent the user from typing in their own "junk" characters.

Answer (score -1):

I guess you could take a look at the code this guy provided.

http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?125935-Number-field-with-currency-symbol-thousand-separator-with-international-support

There seems to be a use `useThousandSeparator` attributes that you can set.

Hope this helps

Comment: That's not working. Also, its absent from the documentation, so I doubt it exists

Comment: It does not exist in Sencha but in the plugin that the guy created. So I though the OP could take a look at the plugin's code to see how it makes use of the useThouseSeparator config.